# Is it possible to create a rollup column for a query?

Tags: azure-devops

I am attempting to create a rollup column for Feature 123 to sum up story points for all User Stories who have Feature 123 as a parent. Furthermore, I would like this rollup column to show up as a query result.

However, I noticed that if I click "Queries", there is no "Add a rollup column". How can I configure Azure DevOps so that the "Add a rollup column" shows up underneath "Add a column"?

[image]

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/track-the-progress-of-work-using-rollup-columns/) is some rollup column documentation I've been following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Add a rollup column** feature is not supported for **Queries**. Please check [document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops#work-item-query-charts-and-rollup) for where Rollup can be used.

Alternatively you can create a flat list query that sums the values of a field you specify as described in above document. Check here for more information about [work tracking charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops).

You can also [submit a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click suggest a feature and choose Azure devops) to Microsoft development team, hope they will consider adding rollup feature to query results.